# Wicked pdf doesn't work at server. but worked locally.(Seems like can not find template)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> RuntimeError (PDF could not be generated! Error: Failed loading page http://works

This is production.log. I've ensure wkhtmltopdf(0.9.5) installed at server. And specify wkhtmltopdf path to the wicked_pdf initialize file.

I had try two different way to implement the logic.

render a pdf format. like this

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf         => "pdf_file_name",
             :template    => 'retailers/scorecard.pdf.erb'
    end
  end
```

Or save the template to a file and send this file to user

```
  file_name = "pdffile.pdf"
  pdf = render_to_string :pdf => file_name, :template    => 'retailers/scorecard.pdf.erb'

  file_path = Rails.root.join("public", "pdfs", file_name) 
  File.open(file_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
  end

  send_file file_path
```

Both of them are work locally but doesn't work at server. and log are same as above. The only different I can think is My OS is mac but server is Ubuntu.

btw I've use wkhtmltopdf in command line at server. It works.

Comment: Both logs are the same as the one above or only in production the logged message is like the one above?

Comment: Only in server. Locally whatever dev or production are work fine. I'm confuse why it try to find "h t t p://works" .

Comment: I've moved your solution to a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a X-server installed on the ubuntu box? Wkhtmltopdf depends on it, or at least on xvfb. Xvfb replaces the graphical environment for this particular case.

If you want to go with xvfb you can do the following:

```
apt-get install xvfb    
Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 640x480x16 &
```

Line 2 starts a a xvfb frame buffer in the background that can be used by wkhtmltopdf.

Make sure you are using the correct version (32/64 bit) depending on your system's architecture!

Comment: I have use wkhtmltopdf in command line at server. It works. So I think this isn't a environment problem but a configuration problem..

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Use another way

```
file_name = "example.pdf"
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string('example.pdf.erb'))

  file_path = Rails.root.join("public", "pdfs", file_name) 
  File.open(file_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
  end

  send_file file_path
```